# Read specific information in a text file

Tags: c++, text, matrix

As my title specifies, 
I need to read information within a text file (C++).
I saw many example involving text file organized as list of numbers or strings, but in my case I need to extract the information within a file (example.txt) organized as follow:

```
// This is the begin of the text file:
Here_the_coordinates_are_going_to_be_listed
Start
x    y    z
0    0    0
1    0    0
1    1    0
0    1    0
End
```

And I would ideally read and store in "std::vector" the information contained between "Start" and "End"  such that matrix is a N x 3 vector:

```
matrix[i][j] =  0    0    0
                1    0    0
                1    1    0
                0    1    0
```

I gave a look at the tutorials and all I've got so far was:

```
  std::array<std::array<int , 5>, 7> matrix;

  std::ifstream file("../test/matrix.txt");

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  {
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      file >> matrix[i][j];
  }
```

which allows me to read a file where only numbers are written.

Thank you very much,

dARIO

Comment: Is that all the code you've got?

Comment: No, I am able to read and store the matrix if the file would be simple, but in this case I don't know how to fill the matrix from line 5 of the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ on how to read/write to files, then you can go through the file and look for the first relevant character (or last irelvant character, like the z in this case) and then just loop through all the relevant characters and store them in a 2 dimensional array (could be dynamic too if you do not know the length of your list)

EDIT:

So here is an example from that website of how to read a text file it is from the link above (which I updated, I'm very sorry about that) So basically the idea is as you see below, you open the file and then you just loop through every single line here (I think you can also use getchar for characters instead, which is probably better for you, but I am not too sure how excatly that works, you're just gonna have to mess around with that a bit, I'm sure you'll get it :) ) So here the line is just saved  in a string and then printed out using cout, but you could manipulate the string further to find your data, I hope that helps! Feel free to ask again if I wasn't clear enough

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        } 
        myfile.close();
     }

     else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, certainly it will be dynamic. For the time being unfortunately this tutorial is not helping me. Certainly due to my few skills, but I do not even find the part which should help me. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I am so so sorry!! I gave you the wrong link on accident! Completly my fault! but I updated the link and answer, hopefully it helps now! Just feel free to ask again, I'm so sorry again!!

Comment: It's ok jundl, I also have my responsability 'cause my question was not clear. By the way, I would really appreciate if you could help me a bit more. Actually my problem is right there... where you say that I have to mess around. I've been able to read the lines I desire since the beginning (the one with x y z and the one with End in my .txt file) but I am stuck there, because I do not find the way to store the line number, so I cannot read and store my coordinates into a matrix. BR       PS: I read the tutorial.     PS2: I could post my program if it may help

Comment: so basically you have every line you desire in form of a string but you do not know how to get them from the string into the array, is that right? if that is your problem you can just use a for loop and check if the character is indeed one of the one's you are looking for, and if it is you can put it into the 2-d array (you can do this by using 2 counter variables, one for the x and one for the y to keep track of where you are in the array)